# On implementing a OpenFileDialog box,"System.IO.FileStream" is appearing on the resultant edittext box rather than the filename and path. How?

Tags: c++, mfc

On implementing an openFileDialog function in visual studio in a dialog based MFc application, I'm getting "System.IO.FileStream" as the result on the edittext box

I have included the code with this question. In the DoDataExchange function, IDC_EDIT1 is the ID for the edittext box.

On executing this code, The FileOpen dialog opens and on selecting the file, "System.IO.FileStream" is what appears on the edittext box.

```
void CMFCApplication6Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, path);

}

void CMFCApplication6Dlg::OnBnClickedBrowse()
{
    System::IO::Stream^ myStream;

    System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;


    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    UpdateData(true);
    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr)
        {
            path = myStream->ToString();
            UpdateData(false);
            myStream->Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem lies in the statement

`path = myStream->ToString();`

The `ToString()` function returns "a string that represents the current object". This is the string you see when you attempt to display the path (a string describing the object type, hence System.IO.FileStream).

EDIT: As requested, I believe the path can be retrieved using the `FileDialog.FileName` property. So
`openFileDialog1->FileName` could be used to access the path.

Comment: Then how can i retrieve the file name and path out of the stream object. Suggest me if any major modifications needed to be done on this code.

Comment: Edited to reflect a specific suggestion